# WSO2 Identity Server Adding additional user properties

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Idenity server to keep my users to application.
Now client asked me to keep some more information associated with his user profile.Like Age , District , Location etc... 
How can i add more additional custom user properties to WSO2?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding custom claims in identity server and mapping them to the attributes in underlying userstore. Refer the doc [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Adding+Claim+Mapping) on how to do that.

The Age attribute should be handled specially because it changes by time. Extending userstore manager as in [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+User+Attributes#ManagingUserAttributes-Writingcustomattributes) would be an option for such attributes